# Comparing two timestamps from mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, timestamp

I have two datetime variables retrieved from mysql.
one is equal to 'now()' and the other represents the last time a row was changed.

I need to compare these two datetime values to get the difference between the two.

This is what i was attempting (my reading in from Mysql is handled by a bespoke web api)...

```
 'get the current time
 Dim nowtime As DateTime = readsql("now()", "hosts", "")
    Console.WriteLine("NOW IS : " & nowtime)

    'read in all the rows
    Dim hosts() As String = readsql("hostname", "hosts", "chk_ping=1").ToString.Split("|")

    For Each host As String In hosts
        If Not host.Contains("No results found") Then
            Dim thishostip As String = readsql("IP", "hosts", "hostname='" & host & "'")
            Dim thishostlastpoll As DateTime = readsql("last_poll", "hosts", "hostname='" & host & "'")

            If thishostip.Contains("No results found") Then Exit For
            Console.WriteLine("HOST TIME IS:"  & thishostlastpoll.ToString)

            Dim timedifference As Integer = DateTime.Compare(nowtime, thishostlastpoll)
            Console.WriteLine("Time diff for " & host & " is : " & timedifference)


        End If

    Next
```

My datetime values are coming in like so...

```
 18/01/2016 10:53:00
 18/01/2016 10:52:52
```

and no error/exception is thrown, but regardless of the difference, 'timedifference' is only ever 1.

I suspect its something to do with the format of the datetime not being what VB wants, but I cant find anything for converting mysql to vb datetimes, just the other way round.

any direction would be appriciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not the "format" dates do not have a format.  Once you get the 2 values into DateTime vars they are Net DateTime vars, if Net did not like something about them you'd get an error.  If I compare those 2 values it works fine.  Can you show `readsql` and tell us the datatype used in the DB

Comment: readsql is a http call out to a php api which handles all of the database interactions. 

I think I'll use a tickcounter rather than comparing the actual times, negates this problem all together then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I suspect its something to do with the format of the datetime not being what VB wants, but I cant find anything for converting mysql to vb datetimes, just the other way round.`

You might be confused about 1 or 2 things.

First, dates do not have a format.  Formats are how computers (or computer code you write) displays a date to the user.  A Net (not VB *per se*) `DateTime` is a value indicating a point in time stored as a very large number.  Since `635886720000000000` (today's date) makes little sense to most of us, the `DateTime` type expresses it in conventional format.

The `MySql` data provider objects are perfectly capable of converting data back and forth from Net `DateTime` values to however MySql needs to store it based on the column definition.

The real issue may be here:

```vb
Dim timedifference As Integer = DateTime.Compare(nowtime, thishostlastpoll)
```

Given the variable name and how you display it, you might be confused as to what  `DateTime.Compare` does.  From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Compares two instances of DateTime and returns an integer that indicates whether the first instance is earlier than, the same as, or later than the second instance.

Given 2 MySql columns defined as `TIMESTAMP(3)` and read into NET `DateTime` vars:

```vb
Console.WriteLine("A is {0}", dtA)
Console.WriteLine("B is {0}", dtB)
Console.Write("Compare is {0}, therefore ", DateTime.Compare(dtA, dtB))

Select Case DateTime.Compare(dtA, dtB)
    Case Is < 0         ' ie -1
        Console.WriteLine("dtA is earlier")
    Case Is > 0
        Console.WriteLine("dtB is earlier")
    Case 0
        Console.WriteLine("dtA and dtB are exactly equal")
End Select
```

Result:

> A is 1/18/2016 8:39:51 AM
>   B is 1/18/2016 8:40:11 AM
>   Compare is -1 therefore, dtA is earlier

What can be a little confusing about `DateTime.Compare` is that the result indicates the *earlier/smaller* value while most all the other `Compare` methods indicate the larger.

Comment: How exactly right you are.... the '1' that i am being left with is actually correct and i misunderstood the function. Thank you for pointing this out. 
I have another method to achieve what I need and am implementing now.

Answer (score 1):

Instead try subtracting the two datetime values like below which will return a `TimeStamp` value. BTW, your current datetime format is `dd/mm/yyyy` which I think should be `mm/dd/yyyy`

```
Dim timedifference As TimeStamp = nowtime - thishostlastpoll
```

Comment: I get this....'Error 6 Value of type 'System.TimeSpan' cannot be converted to 'Date'.'

How would I go about changing the format received from mysql?
Also, i used 'datetime' and 'date' as using 'timestamp' gives me "Type 'timestamp is not defined'